# How to keep contacts to a GROUP for a limited period?

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, groups

We have kids activity event that runs for a year, for example, event name is KIDS CLUB - 2019. Registration is done by webform. We capture parent details as relationship and added to PARENT GROUP. Kids details added as contact & participant, added to KIDS GROUP. That was easy part!

For the next year we would need to create an event called KIDS CLUB - 2020. Some kids and parent may remain same and some new kids will signup. We do not want to send any related email to those parents who has not signed up for 2020.

How can we remove the parents & kids automatically that would not signup for next year? Perhaps some of you can think of an alternative approach to deal with it. Please feel free to suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think you can create a smart group based on Event type and Registration date this year. This will have contacts who will be registered for an event for 2019 and then will be removed automatically when its 2020.

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Smart Group of people related to people in a specified group.

[image]

So make Group of Participants 2020 (P20).

Make Smart Group of contacts Parents of Participants 2020 (PP20)

You already say you have a group for PP19

Use the Custom Search = Include/Exclude to work out PP19 - PP20.

That should give you a list of Parents of those who participated in 2019 but do not have kids participating in 2020

Answer (score 2):

I'd either remove everyone from the two groups (PARENTS GROUP, KIDS GROUP), or if you want a record of who was in the group last year rename them to have a year suffix and then create two new groups.

Unfortunately it's not possible to search based on participant status of a related contact. A couple of ways around this:
Give Parents a participant status in the event - which means you could search on this. 
Create an activity on webform submission that records that the parent enrolled a child in the event.

If you wanted you could create a drupal view that joined the parent to the child to the event participation - then use drupal bulk actions to add them to a group.